# How to extract a column in a dataset without row names?

Tags: dataset

Suppose I have an association such as:

```
<|DateObject[{2000, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", 
"Gregorian", -3.`] -> <|"Open" -> 1.8720275163650513`, 
"High" -> 1.8720275163650513`, "Low" -> 1.8720275163650513`, 
"Close" -> 1.8720275163650513`, "Volume" -> 3.538944`*^10, 
"Dividends" -> 0.`, "Stock Splits" -> 0.`|>, 
DateObject[{2000, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", 
"Gregorian", -3.`] -> <|"Open" -> 1.7684688568115237`, 
"High" -> 1.7684688568115237`, "Low" -> 1.7684688568115237`, 
"Close" -> 1.7684688568115234`, "Volume" -> 2.886144`*^10, 
"Dividends" -> 0.`, "Stock Splits" -> 0.`|>, 
DateObject[{2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", 
"Gregorian", -3.`] -> <|"Open" -> 1.7506240606307983`, 
"High" -> 1.7506240606307983`, "Low" -> 1.7506240606307983`, 
"Close" -> 1.7506240606307983`, "Volume" -> 4.30336`*^10, 
"Dividends" -> 0.`, "Stock Splits" -> 0.`|>, 
DateObject[{2000, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.`}, "Instant", 
"Gregorian", -3.`] -> <|"Open" -> 1.744570255279541`, 
"High" -> 1.744570255279541`, "Low" -> 1.744570255279541`, 
"Close" -> 1.744570255279541`, "Volume" -> 3.405568`*^10, 
"Dividends" -> 0.`, "Stock Splits" -> 0.`|>|>
```

It shows something like:

> [image]

I can take the "High" column with this:

```
Dataset[A][All, "High"]
```

But it outputs this:

[image]

Ie: With the dates. Is there a clean way to make the dates disappear? I know other ways to do it, but perhaps there is a more clean "datasety" way to do it.

Comment: `Dataset[A][Values, "High"]` should do what you want

Comment: Normal[Dataset[data][Values, "High"]] ==> {1.87203, 1.76847, 1.75062, 1.74457}